# PHP convert session variable from array into int

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing session information in an array called 'Auth'. That array contains 2 session information: id and password. My problem is when I am using the id info for quering, it is not working. I am pretty sure it is due to the fact that the id info in my table is an int, and the one from the session array isn't. So my question is to know how to convert that session id variable into an int. Here below the function in which I am using $_SESSION(['Auth']['id']). Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

The PHP code where I am using the session info:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("connect.inc.php");

function isLogged(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['Auth']) && isset($_SESSION['Auth']['id']) && isset($_SESSION['Auth']['pass'])){

            extract($_SESSION['Auth']);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usr_users WHERE usr_id = '$id' AND usr_pass = '$pass'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Here the PHP code where I set the session info:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("connect.inc.php");


$identifiant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);
$pass = sha1($_POST['pass']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usr_pseudo = '$identifiant' AND usr_pass = '$pass'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);   
    $_SESSION['Auth']=array(
        'id'=>$data['usr_id'],
        'pass'=>$pass
    );
}

echo mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
```

Comment: MySQL implicitly converts numeric values if quoted as strings. Something else is going on, such as `$_SESSION['Auth']['Id']` not containing what you think it does.

Comment: "at array contains 2 session information: id and password."  Why are you storing the password in a session?

Comment: Michael, ty trying to help me. Check above the code through which I am creating the session info. It might give you more indication to try help me. Thank you

Comment: Problem solved- It was a syntax error:( Thanks to everyone that has taken time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

`extract()` is a horribly ugly function, and you should wipe its existence out of your mind.

There's no need for it, since it's purely a holdover from PHP's early "lazy" days, when it tried to do everything for you, causing in part the miserable security reputation PHP has.

You can directly embed session variables wherever you want, even when it's an arbitrarily "deep" array reference like your session is:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE id={$_SESSION['Auth']['id']} ...";
```

or even

```
$id = $_SESSION['Auth']['id']'
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE id=$id";
```

will both work the same way, and not litter your variable namespace with useless junk.

Comment: Hello Marc. Thank you very much for the info. I will stop using extract(). Unfortunately it is not solving the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast any variable into any type by using the cast methods.

```
$usr_id = (int)$data['usr_id']
```

This would return a type of integer. If the id includes anything else but integers, 0 is returned.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Hello Richard. I tried that already. It isn't helping unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should not query DB each time you'd like to check if the user is logged in. And you don't need to store password in the seesion.
You have to query db only once when you login user (your second part of the code).

And it would be better if you create a simple wrapper for your auth logic. Something like this simple class with static functions:

```
<?php
class Auth
{
  public static function login($identifiant, $password)
  {
    // query db then
    // $_SESSION['Auth']['id'] = value from db
    return self::id();
  }

  public static function isLogged()
  {
    return (bool)self::id()
  }

  public static function id()
  {
    return (isset($_SESSION['Auth']['id'])) ? $_SESSION['Auth']['id'] : false)
  }

  public static function logout()
  {
    $_SESSION['Auth'] = array();
  }
}


// usage
Auth::login($_POST['identifiant'], $_POST['password']);
if (Auth::isLogged()) {
  $sql = "select * from posts where user = " . Auth::id() . "";
}
Auth::logout();
```

Comment: Hello, i am not checking to know if the user is logged In. I am checking that a real user is loged in. For security reason it seems to me not enough to have sessions set. Those sessions have to be accurate and be related to real user accounts. That's why I use the password as session info also.

Comment: You won't get any benefit in security if you will store password in session. It is enough to store id in the session. Also, if you like to check if this is a real user you may add a correspondent query into the Auth::id() method. I just show you an example of much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "pretty sure it is due to the fact that the id info in (your) table is an int, and the one from the session array isn't".

Then here's a simple way to convert your session id from array into a variable ([cast it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)).

```
$id = (int)$_SESSION['id'];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

you should not enclose integers in single quotes in the SQL

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usr_users WHERE usr_id = $id AND usr_pass = '$pass'");
```

Comment: Hello David. Thank you for helping. Unfortunately your idea is not working.

Comment: Numeric values can be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: ahk! only on SO does my intolerance for MySQLs looseness bite me so hard!